# How do I center my title (both horizontally and vertically)?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a centred title, both horizontally and vertically on the page. I'm rather new to latex - so far, I've tried the code below without success:

```
\begin{center}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\end{center}
```

Am I required to use special flags to centre the title?

I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

Comment: What class are you using? `book` or `report` or `article`?If you use the `book` class then you only need to use `\maketitle`.

Comment: I'm using article

Comment: @GonzaloMedina do you have an example I can see somewhere? I'm still very new at this :)

Comment: @blueberryfields, just change the first line of my code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\title{title here}
\author{author here}
\date{date here}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

**Edit:** As pointed out by @Gonzalo Medina, if you want to use the `article` class, just change the first line of the code to `\documentclass[titlepage]{article}`.